# Representing high precision floats in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

We intend to train an ANN with some data which do not fit into float64 or any other existing data types in TensorFlow. For example, an input neuron may receive:

```
1.13760089015656552359796023723738662029191734968655617689014826158791613333
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to represent the data in TensorFlow or Keras?
2. If there is not a clear and convenient solution, do you think that casting the data into complex128 would help us? for example:

   1.137600890156565523597960237237 + 73866202919173496865561768901 **i**

For our case, the more floating-point means more accuracy. So we need to keep them as much as possible.

We prefer to use a GPU so the solution should cover them.

Comment: "For our case, the more floating-point means more accuracy" - I suppose that's true for every case, the question is how much precision you really need, there are very few cases where 64-bit is not enough. There are standards for [quadruple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) and even [octuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octuple-precision_floating-point_format), but those are _very_ rare, and not supported by TF. "Splitting" the number in a complex value wouldn't work, floating point values cannot be "concatenated" like that.

Comment: There is also [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), again not supported in TF, and again rarely needed, which would allow you to have as much precision as you want. In any case, if you are doing neural networks, it usually does not make much sense to use more that 32-bit precision - it's just an approximative machine learning method after all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered preprocessing the data? It's rather rare to see noticeably important divergence with so high precision. It might be also hard to calculate meaningful gradient, when you only operate on such flat space.

Comment: Which kind of preprocessing do you think would help us?
The input data is continuous and the difference between the points lays deep in the floating points.

Comment: So just rescale it to normal distribution and you'll be fine. This [one](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) is most basic. Though you might get into troubles, if your data has outliers.

Comment: https://9gag.com/gag/aMZb4d1

Always remember about it. First you need to understand and prepare your data. Building models comes last.